# Set Service argument after authentication

Tags: php, symfony

One of services in my bundle depends on data comming from external api that is called after user is successful loged in. 
Is there any way to inject argument value into service afeter user authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to set something on authentication success, there is nothing better than making an AuthenticationSuccessHandler. It's processed each time a user successfully logs in and do any action...

Tutorial : http://blog.alterphp.com/2011/10/set-up-authenticationsuccesshandler.html